# Two isolated containers connected by a valve and gas is allowed to pass from one to another container. Associated change in internal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

If we have two isolated containers A and B containing gases in them connected to each other by a very thin tube of negligible volume and a valve is present in the tube .
Initially the conditions of the containers are  :-
Container A - Pressure = p¹ , Temp. = T¹ and Volume = V¹
Container B - Pressure P² , Volume= V² and Temperature = T²
Now the valve is opened to allow both gases to mix together.
Should the internal energy of the system remain constant cos no external energy is supplied to the system , but then I think that the expansion cannot be considered free expansion as there is gas on other side of valve too .
So please explain to me if the internal energy would remain constant or not. Or is
U¹ + U2 = Uf. Applicable.

Comment: If the two containers are rigid an insulated, the first law tells us that, for this combined system, the internal energy is constant.  The real question is whether a significant amount of heat can be transferred through the tube so that, in the end, the temperatures in the two containers are equal or whether negligible heat can be transferred through the tube.

Comment: Ya the end temperature is supposedly equal.

Comment: That makes things much simpler.  That means that the final temperatures and pressures are equal.